# Change the label for an optiongroup created with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to display a HTML select element with optiongroups by using the angularjs select directive.

However I would like to control the value of the optgroup label attribute (every label should be the same '-------------'). Is there any way to achieve this?

Also could it be that there is a problem when using an group by key of '0'?

A working plunker can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/i8rBdpQYYazYLIbjajjS

**EDIT:**

I would like the selecto to look like this:

```
name 2
-------
name 1
-------
name 3
name 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any option to change `optgroup` label from current [ngOptions](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) !

There is a workaround with writing your own directive. In your `HTML`

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
            ng-options="item.text group by item.group for item in data" 
            optgroup-label="---"></select>
```

And the `optgroupLabel` directive looks like

```
directive('optgroupLabel', function($timeout){
  return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      $timeout(function(){
          $(element).find('optgroup').each(function(i,e){
            $(e).prop('label', attrs.optgroupLabel);
          })
      },0);
    }
  }
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uqr6NnNYOhvj3oQGwptd?p=preview)